# Boostrap doesn't want to apply justify-content-between in card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

With Bootstrap 4, I am making a horizontal card for classified ad and want in the header to title of the ad to be on the left and price on the right. Using django template:

```
<section class="card">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="{{ad.thumbnail.url}}" alt="" class="img fluid card-img ad-image-list">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <header class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <h6>{{ad.title}}</h6>
                        <h6> {{ad.price}}$ </h6>
                        <hr>
                    </header>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ad.description}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I get this:
[image]

Why doesnt wanna apply `<header class"d-flex justify-content-between">` ?

Comment: remove the hr inside the header (closing as typo issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using `<hr>` in flex container and `<hr>` going to right. Just remove the `hr` inside `header`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="card">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/536/354" alt="" class="img fluid card-img ad-image-list">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="card-body">
        <header class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <h6>Title</h6>
          <h6>Price</h6>
        </header>
        <hr>
        <p class="card-text">{{ad.description}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```